# Converting commands with arguments to expl3

Tags: expl3

How would one convert this to expl3 version ?

```
\newcommand{\piston_bfblue}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{#1}}}
```

Comment: You have seen multiple instances of `\cs_new:N(p)n` in your previous questions.

Comment: Got to chuck out the `[1]` used in my example, then.

Comment: It is part of `\newcommand` syntax, but not `\NewDocumentCommand` syntax.

Comment: Is it always required to use the protected version of function when used with  `\NewDocumentCommand` ?

Comment: what has `\NewDocumentCommand` got to do with this question??? You asked for an expl3 definition so `\cs_new_protected:Nn\piston_bfblue:n{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{#1}}}` which would be the answer if this wasn't a duplicate of any of hundreds of earlier questions, including several of yours.

Comment: Because you described that `\newcommand` was Latex2e and now one uses L3 Layer.  It was mentioned in discussion about tho geometry commands I had.

Comment: No I am not suggesting using a variant, but the code had an example of defining a one-argument command before defining a variant of it, surely you can extract 1 line out of a two line example.

Comment: Users would call the command `\wvBfblue`.  Might need the `\NewDocumentCommand` because I was using `\newcommand` in both this question and the previous one about setting the geometry.

Comment: what's the point of defining commands for colours? why not just let them use standard colour syntax?? But anyway yes you might need `\NewDocumentCommand` in some other part of your code but its unrelated to this question

Comment: For specific documents, they can just use a short name.

Comment: so they have to learn new commands just for a specific document, what advantage does that have? In a document you should never be using a command that means bold-blue anyway, define meaningful commands such as `\section` and then define the formatting of `\section` elsewhere to be bold and blue.